# Is Dependency Resolver (MEF/Unity) the only way to resolve the View from the ViewModel in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, mef

We are starting to adopt the MVVM pattern in WPF, so far we have separated the ViewModel from View, and we have created the `Command` classes. But in all cases, we initialize the View at first and generate the ViewModel in the code-behind. I guess it doesn't explore the full benefit of MVVM. For example, when a new UI component should be generated by a `Command`, I fee that the `Command` mixes the ViewModel and View up since it needs to be aware of both and create both of them. There is no clear separation.

And now I have another problem which I think can also be related to this problem: in the WPF application we need to host a WCF service, which takes the request from a different application in the same machine, and initialize the corresponding WPF controls. Since we are hosting the service in a non-UI thread (we don't want to have the host in the code-behind of a `UserControl`), the resulting `UserControl` can't be generated in the hosting thread. So I guess now I must initialize the ViewModel and then try to resolve the corresponding View.

I have some experience before about using MEF as dependency injection and using EventAggregator to inform the generation of a new ViewModel. But since it will bring many changes to our current project, I was wondering, do I have some other option to resolve the View?

So far our UI is still pretty simple but in the long term we will have the need to create a sophisticated UI. But a further question is: should MEF/Unity be always used in order to adopt MVVM pattern for a sophisticated UI? Now I feel that in order to separate the ViewModel and View, they are sort of a must. Am I correct?

UPDATE:

Some answers point to me that I can simply have a DataTemplate which tells the XAML how to render my ViewModel. For example, I can declare a `ContentControl` in a a main UserControl (let me call it UC_Host), which will choose the View depending on the type of ViewModel, and the DataContext of the `ContentControl` is bind to the ViewModel I generated. To my understanding, it is feasible, e.g., if my UC_Host is always present and only one UC_Host is available to host the UC.

But in our project, we actually want to display the generated UC in new `Window`, and the number of these `Window` are not limited (MDI is still absent in WPF and the multi-window layout is our current solution to some tasks). It means that we don't have the dominating uniqie UC_Host on top of the new `Windows` so it is also not easy to bind to ViewModel from there.

That's why I am seeking the solution to let my MainView resolve the View (because only in UI thread it can generate the UIElement and generate a new `Window` probably in its code-behind). Directly data-binding is not possible I guess

Comment: ViewModels creating UserControls isn't MVVM.  You'd bind to models exposed by properties of the VM, and use DataTemplates to populate the UI with controls based on the type of model.  If you use INPC properties, you can access VM properties across threads without worries.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to follow MVVM, where View is on the highest level, you should never put any code (not even in constructor) in a view. You implement logic in ViewModels, creates Views to show data properly and let the application to bind them together. It does not matter, that you don't have a dedicated main window, you can always put DataTemplate-s in App.xaml or in any other resources as far as you merge them into the App.xaml. Showing UserControls in separate windows is not quite different than showing them as separate tabs.

If you need MDI for WPF, you can use this one: http://mdicontainer.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTemplates:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelClass}">
    <views:ViewClass />
</DataTemplate>
```

This templates can be declared as XAML resources.

**Update:**
In this cases, wouldn't it be better to use Unity and resolve your viewmodels from code behind? I'm actually doing it this way for cases where the container of my views is not an ItemsControl:

```
public MyView(MyViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = vm;
}
```

And let Unity resolve the ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have a problem since we actually want to display the newly-generated UserControl in a new windows. Please see my update to my original post for further detail

Answer (score 0):

Use CaliburnMicro. with **ViewModel first** approach.

http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Conventions

basicly use reflection to find **FooView** for every **FooViewmodel**